# jQuery onClick function didn't work after change of id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating follow button using AJAX in Laravel. When I click follow, it will turn into unfollow with the change of id. I tried to click unfollow button again, it didn't execute unfollow on click function but remain the previous follow on click function.

**HTML**

```
 <a id="followAnchor" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" /><i class="fa icon-user-follow"></i> Follow</a>
                                                                     </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#followAnchor').on("click", function(e){
var followId = document.getElementById('followAnchor');
 $.ajax({
          url: "{{ URL::route('follow-post') }}",
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify(arr),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {

          if(response.errors)
          {

          }
          else if (response.success){


            followId.innerHTML = "<i class='fa icon-user-follow'></i>" + "Unfollow";
            document.getElementById('followAnchor').id = 'unfollowAnchor';
          }
    });
}

$('#unfollowAnchor').on("click", function(e){
    var unfollowId = document.getElementById('unfollowAnchor');

    $.ajax({
          url: "{{ URL::route('unfollow-post') }}",
          type: 'POST',
          data: JSON.stringify(arr),
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response) {

          if(response.errors)
          {

          }
          else if (response.success){
            unfollowId.innerHTML = "<i class='fa icon-user-follow'></i>" + "Follow";
            document.getElementById('unfollowAnchor').id = 'followAnchor';
          }
    });
});
```

Comment: Once you chage id of element DOM will not recognize new element. Try to bind element with document. Like this $(document).on("click",".back", function(event){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Events do not magically get bound after they are changed. Once the code has run it does not keep checking for new elements.

- You either need to unbind/bind the event when you change the id/ add new elements.
- Do not change the id, just add logic into the original click (what most devs do)
- Or use event bubbling.

Bubbling example:

```
$(document).on("click", "#followAnchor", function(e){ /* code here */ });        
$(document).on("click", "#unfollowAnchor", function(e){ /* code here */ });
```

Comment: I always wondered why it is named "bubbling", If I say it event delegation then am I wrong or just the same meaning?

Comment: @Manoz Event-Delegation is the method to capture the event-bubbling from (dynamical) elements.You can read more [here](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/05/what-does-event-bubbling-mean/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), because you are register a event-listiner on an element that not exist by that time.

```
$('#unfollowAnchor').on("click", function(e){
```

has to be

```
$(document).on("click", '#unfollowAnchor',function(e){
```

Instead of using IDs here, I would go with adding or removing specific classes:

```
$(followId).addClass('unfollow').removeClass('follow');
```

as an example.